# How do I get a button clicked data in this conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm making a rock paper scissors game right now. I'm trying to compare the users input and the computer's automatically generated answer in an if statement, but I can't figure out how to find the user's input.

Edit: Here's the rest of my code. I've changed a few things from my compare function. Still nothing works. But I hope that by adding my HTML and JavaScript you'd be able to figure out what is going on.

Here's my code:

```
function showInstruct() {
            var show = document.getElementById('hideInstruct');
            if (show.style.display === "none") {
                show.style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                show.style.display = "none"
            }
        }

        function hideButtons() {
            document.getElementById('buttonDiv').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'flex';
            document.getElementById('nextRound').style.display = 'none';

            revealRps();

            setCountdown();
        }

        function setCountdown() {
            var numberS = 3;
            var x = setInterval(function() {
            document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = numberS;
            numberS--;
            if (numberS < 0) {
                clearInterval(x);
                document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = "VS";
                document.getElementById('rps').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('nextRound').style.display = 'flex';
                document.getElementById('input').style.display = 'none';
                compare();
            }
            }, 950);
        }

        function revealRps() {
            document.getElementById('rps').style.display = 'flex';
            document.getElementById('nextRound').style.display = 'none';
        }

        function hideRps() {
            document.getElementById('rps').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('input').style.display = 'flex';
        }

        function compare() {
            var random = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
            var comp = Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length);
            var compDraw = random[comp];
            if($('rock').click == true && compDraw == 'scissors')
            {
            document.getElementById('rockBeats').style.display = 'flex';
            trackedValue.rock = true
            }
            else if ($('paper').click == true && compDraw == 'rock')
            {
                document.getElementById('paperBeats').style.display = 'flex';
                trackedValue.paper = true
            }
            else if ($('scissors').click == true && compDraw == 'paper')
            {
                document.getElementById('scissorsBeats').style.display = 'flex';
                trackedValue.scissors = true
            }
            else if ($('rock').click == true && compDraw == 'paper')
            {
                document.getElementById('paperBeats').style.display = 'flex';
                trackedValue.paper = true
            }
            else if ($('paper').click == true && compDraw == 'scissors')
            {
                document.getElementById('scissorsBeats').style.display = 'flex';
                trackedValue.scissors = true
            }
            else if ($('scissors').click == true && compDraw == 'rock') 
            {
                document.getElementById('rockBeats').style.display = 'flex';
                trackedValue.rock = true
            }

        }
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Extreme Rock Paper Scissors!</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0l">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=New+Rocker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=New+Rocker&family=Schoolbell&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Long+Cang&family=New+Rocker&family=Schoolbell&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RPS.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RPS.js"></script>

    <div class="titleWords">
        <h1>EXTREME ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!</h1>
    </div>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="beats">
        <div id="rockBeats">ROCK BEATS SCISSORS</div>
        <div id="paperBeats">PAPER BEATS ROCK</div>
        <div id="scissorsBeats">SCISSORS BEATS PAPER</div>
        <div id="draw">DRAW</div>
        <div id="noInput">YOU DIDN'T CLICK ANYTHING. COMPUTER AUTOMATICALLY WINS</div>
    </div>
    <div id="buttonDiv">
        <button id="playButton" = onclick="hideButtons()">PLAY GAME</button>
        <button id="instructions" onclick="showInstruct()">INSTRUCTIONS<button>

    </div>


    <div id="hideInstruct">
        <p>The premise - This is war! And you must choose your attacks carefully.
        When you press PLAY GAME a countdown clock will countdown from 3. During that time you need to make a selection of how you're going to attack. Are you going to use Rock, Paper, or Scissors? 
        </p>
        <br>
        <p>The logistics - If you choose Rock and the computer chooses scissors, you crush those scissors into dust!  If you choose scissors and the computer chooses paper, you slice the paper into shreds! And if you choose paper and the computer chooses rock, you smear the rock with the a major paper-cut! However, if you choose Rock and the computer chooses Paper than you lose. In essense, the computer can do the same things to you that you can do to it. If you and the computer both draw the same thing, than it's considered a draw and nothing happens. And one more thing. If time runs out and you've selected nothing, than the computer automatically wins the point.</p>
        <br>
        <p>How to win - For each victory, that's one point. The first player to reach 3 points wins the game!</p>
    </div>

    <article id="countdown">
        <p id="number">3</p>
    </article>

    <footer id="rps">
        <button type="button" id="rock" onclick="hideRps()">ROCK</button>
        <button type="button" id="paper" onclick="hideRps()">PAPER</button>
        <button type="button" id="scissors" onclick="hideRps()">SCISSORS</button>
    </footer>

    <div id="input">
        <p id="locked">Your answer is locked in</p>
    </div>

    <div id="nextRound">
        <button id="nextButton" onclick="hideButtons()">Next Round</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('rock').click` <= it's not clear what you are trying to do with this logic.  `rock` is not a valid css selector, unless you have some how constructed your own `<rock>` HTML element.  And `click` off of a jQuery object is a method.

Comment: I do have an element called 'rock; in my HTML

Comment: I've edited my post, it should contain the rest of my code now

Comment: You do not have a `<rock>` element.  You have an element with an id of `rock`.  Those are two different selectors.  And you did not address what you are trying to do with the `.click` logic

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your ques, you can use an object to keep track of the value

```
let trackedValue = {rock:false,paper:false,sicssors:false };

        function compare() {
        var random = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
        var comp = Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length);
        var compDraw = random[comp];
        if($('rock').click == true && compDraw == 'scissors')
        {
            document.getElementById('rockBeats').style.display = 'flex';
            trackedValue.rock = true
        }
        // remaining code
```

Comment: That didn't work. I edited my post and added the rest of my code